# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'INSERT URL NAME' not found

Tags: django, django-forms

I am learning about Django forms and am struggling to render a basic 'results' page for the form.

I would be greatly appreciative if somebody could point out what I'm doing wrong! Thanks in advance :)

**ERROR**

```
NoReverseMatch at /search_query/
Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://ozxlitwi.apps.lair.io/search_query/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 632
Python Executable:  /mnt/data/.python-3.6/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/mnt/project',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 1 Jun 2018 10:00:20 +0900
```

**views.py**

```
def search_query(request):

    # If POST request, process the Form data:
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Create a form instance and populate it with the data from the request (binding):
        form = SearchQueryForm(request.POST)

        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results'))

    else:
        form = SearchQueryForm()

    context = {'form':form}
        return render (request, 'mapping_twitter/search_query.html', context)

def results(request):
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'mapping_twitter/results.html', context)
```

**mapping_twitter/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'mapping_twitter'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.search_query, name='search-query'),
    path('results/', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

**mapping_data/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search_query/', include('mapping_twitter.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/search_query', permanent=True)),
]
```

**mapping_twitter/results.html**

```
<!--- DRAFT --->
Display search results here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `results` endpoint is in an app called `mapping_twitter`, then you can get at it with `reverse('mapping_twitter:results')`.

Further reading on reversing namespaced URLs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls